# vba ie.navigate doesn't work

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I need to navigate to a page using VBA. I created the code bellow and it worked just fine until I reinstalled Windows. I don't know if this is the cause, but it is not working anymore.

There are tho cases:

1. If I'm not logged in before running the macro

   The first part, for logging onto the page is working, but when I try to navigate to "http://cltd.ro/catalogsearch/result/?q=60041", I get an error "Method 'Navigate' of object 'IWebBrowser 2' failed".
2. If I'm already logged on to the site

   On the other hand, if I'm already logged in before running the macro, the code is working and I get to the desired page, but the code gets stuccked in to the loop "Do/DoEvents/Loop Until ie.readystate = 4" forever and I cannot continue

Please help!
Thanks!

```
Sub xx()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    ie.Visible = True
    AppActivate ie
    apiShowWindow ie.hwnd, 3
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://cltd.ro/customer/account/login/"
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

    On Error Resume Next    'in case I'm already loggen in
    Call ie.Document.getElementById("email").setattribute("value", "dfgsdfg")   'not real value ;-)
    Call ie.Document.getElementById("pass").setattribute("value", "dfgsdfg")    'not real value ;-)
    Call ie.Document.getElementById("send2").Click
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
    On Error GoTo 0         'cancels the resume next

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    link = "http://cltd.ro/catalogsearch/resuilt/?q=60041"
    ie.navigate link
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

'Other lines of code ...............

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your actual question, but:

(1) You should always have a timeout in your "wait until document ready" loops. Otherwise, those loops can wait forever if the page does not go ready. In fact when I tried navigating manually (via the IE URL bar) to "http://cltd.ro/customer/account/login/", it sat there spinning for quite some time, until I gave up and hit stop. Your code should detect cases where the document takes too ling to go ready, and reply with something like "Website hasn't responded for 60 seconds, do you want to keep waiting? [yes] [No]".

(2) You don't allow for the case where the page *does* go ready, but it's not the page you wanted. For example, if the website returns an error, or IE decides to time it out, you'll get a page with a URL of the form "res://..." - not the page you actually asked for. You can't just assume that you actually got the right page.

So your existing code is ok for a 1-off script, but not sufficiently robust for proper production use.